# Finding where an env variable is set

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

I have the problem that my `http_proxy` is wrongly set, whenever I start a new terminal:

```
» echo $http_proxy 
http://http://127.0.0.1:1234/
```

Which is ... bad. I have a bug somewhere in my environment setup. Let's try to find it. For that I will show the value of the variable at the very start of `.bashrc`. I create a *new* terminal, and the wrong value is already there for me to see:

```
http_proxy=http://http://127.0.0.1:1234/
»
```

Ok, so either one of these must be true:

1. the desktop process (the one starting the terminal) is already 
   exporting the wrong value,
2. the value is set by `bash` **before** `.bashrc` is parsed

Let me check the environment of the parent process of the current shell:

```
» pstree -ahp myuser
...
  ├─gnome-terminal-,3807
  │   ├─bash,3814
  │   │   └─pstree,17329 -ahp myuser
```

Let's check the environment of the parent process, `gnome-terminal`:

```
» cat /proc/3807/environ | tr \\0 \\n | grep -i http_proxy
```

Nothing, zilch, nada!

What about `bash`?

```
» cat /proc/3814/environ | tr \\0 \\n | grep -i http_proxy
HTTP_PROXY=http://http://127.0.0.1:1234/
http_proxy=http://http://127.0.0.1:1234/
```

As expected, it is there (this is equivalent of doing `echo $http_proxy`, of course, or doing `cat /proc/self/environ`)

So, it is not in `gnome-terminal`, but it is in `bash`. It must be set somewhere else while loading `bash`, **before** `.bashrc`. I have tried checking `.profile` too, but no luck.

What could be happening before `.bashrc`? What other debugging ideas do you have?

Comment: How are you printing the variable in .bashrc? Also, check the other startup files mentioned in `man bash`: /etc/profile, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login and ~/.profile.

Comment: @l0b0 a simple `echo $http_proxy` at the beginning of `.bashrc`. There is nothing special in the other files you mention ...

Comment: Just to clarify, you are not starting a new shell from an existing one, but closing the terminal and opening a new one?